# How to require(include) a perl file in openshift?

Tags: perl, openshift

I write a.pl and b.pl,
and I include a perl file b.pl in openshift in a.pl:

```
a.pl:
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
require "b.pl";
....
```

but when i push the code to openshift using git
it also say it can't find the b.pl?

```
remote: ! Finding b.pl on cpannetadb failed.
....
remote: ! Couldn't find module or a distribution b.pl
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive'
...
```

anyone know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you try with "absolute path" for b.pl?

Comment: It say

Can't locate /var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/app-root/runtime/repo/b.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/app-root/runtime/repo/libs /var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/perl/perl5lib/lib/perl5/ /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/perl/) at /var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxd/app-root/runtime/repo/perl/a.pl line 2.

Comment: See the answer. You dont have the directory path of script in @INC. you need to add it.

Answer (score 0):

The path of directory containing script needs to be added to @INC.

Add use lib statement before require statement. This will add the directory in the @INC path.

```
use lib "/path/of/directory/where/script/is/present";
```

i.e.

```
use lib "/var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/app-root/runtime/repo";
require "b.pl";
```

or using full absolute path

```
require "/var/lib/openshift/5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxd/app-root/runtime/repo/b.pl";
```

Comment: I tried require '${openshift_repo_dir}b.pl' but still not work
I also tried your says, but they all say "Can't locate  ..........." when i run the perl program

Comment: You need to put hardcoded path i.e. /var/lib/.. etc. The $ variable will not resolve till require call. require statement is one of the first statements to get executed.

Comment: I guess the system can allocate and fetching the file.
But they not build after fetching
says:
remote: gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
remote: /bin/tar: Child returned status
remote: /bin/tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote: ! Failed to unpack b.pl: no directory
remote: ! Failed to fetch distribution

Comment: I am not getting you. Can you clear? Are you still getting error?

Comment: yes, still geting error after change the require to abs. path

Comment: Ok. This error is now not from .pl(I guess), or can you paste more code of `a.pl` or `b.pl` which contains tar command etc. The issue looks like that "it is expecting a module to unpack and install". Post more code of a.pl

Comment: the code work seperately. but once i include another will cause error.
i guess i omitted some setting in openshift